# "href" should not empty and link should not work too

Tags: html, css

Senario: I write "anchor" tag,inside it i give "href".After that requirement is that when i click on the link it should do nothing,but we cannot left empty "href" tag too.How could this possible?

Comment: Just set `href="#"`

Comment: why can you not leave the href attribute off?

Comment: Actually it's my trainer requirement that you won't leave HREF empty,and it should do nothing too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kindly use

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

This should solve your issue.

since the HREF may also be used to identify sections within a document, the HREF contains two components: the URL, which is the actual link, and the clickable text that appears on the page, called the "anchor text."

you could use

```
<a href="#idOfTheAnchorText"></a>
```

or

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

which essentially means that a void do nothing since evaluation of 0 using void calculates to `undefined` primitive value.

Comment: An explanation why this works, what it actually does and what side effects are to expect would greatly improve your answer.

Comment: thanks,better to use href="javascript:void(0);" as in response it do nothing and also we not leave href value empty

Answer (score 2):

Standard practice way of declaring empty `href` would be to use `href="#"` or  `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Explanation:

`href="#"` it's a simple and quick fix, but adds an extra entry to the browser history when clicked.

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="arrow">Link</a>` explicitly add a null-effect href attribute, so when clicked it doesn't have any effect and also does't mess with the browser history.

Comment: An explanation of the advantages and disadvantages (side effects) of the two solutions would be a great improvement of your answer.

Comment: @AqsaShahzadi Happy to know it solved your issue, please mark this answer as accepted in order to help others as well. :)